# Delete a folder in internal storage programmatically in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app where i would automatically delete the images under the whatsapp media folder after a few days periodically . however it seems it's not working.
I have also included
 
     in the manifest file

here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initiateFileCutProcess();
    }
    public void initiateFileCutProcess(){

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "initiateFileCutProcess: intitiating");

            String name = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp\\ Images/";
            File myDir = new File(name);
            Log.d(TAG, "initiateFileCutProcess: delete status : "+deleteDirectory(myDir));
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ name)));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: ",e);
        }
    }
    public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
        if( path.exists() ) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            if (files == null) {
                return true;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
        return( path.delete() );
    }
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what "it's not working" means and **exactly** how you are determining this. For example, if "it's not working" means "I still see the directory in my desktop file manager", the problem is that the `MediaStore` does not know about the deletion.

Comment: Are you requesting permissions in MANIFEST and at RUNTIME to be able to WRITE to external storage?

Comment: Yes i have included them in manifest file,  yes i still see the directory in file manager thats how i found it was not working

Comment: What about run time?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, i can't get what run time means? I did not get any exceptions while running the program , i also tried executing through adb commands from my PC and it was working fine but the same adb commands did not execute in the phone. it returned exit status as 255

Comment: About the runtime permissions, read this article: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html. Taking a second look at your code I don't think it even compiles. You are laking a semi colon (;) in the third line (deleteDirectory(myDir)), which by the way seems to be written outside a method.

Comment: the app was executed in kitkat , so i runtime permissions is not necessary i think

Comment: Do you really need that backslash in the path? It should be fine without it?

Comment: There seemed to be an issue with spaces there fore i used backslashes